# Why my styles in CSS is not working since I gave appropriate name of classes in HTML file and CSS file?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With "meta" links I have all OK and if I add new style in Developer Tools it working correct but if I add new style the same in Sublime Text it's not working it don't do nothing.
This is my HTML code as index.html:

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Ferrari</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="gfx/ferrari-logo.jpg" alt="Ferrari logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <li class="active "><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
</nav>
</div>

   <center>
     <video  width="800" src="video/ferrari_458.mp4" controls></video>
   </center>

<div class="container">
   <h1 class="h1">Design</h1>
   <h4 class="center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</h4><br><br>

   <h4 class="center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</h4><br><br>

   <h4 class="center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</h4>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this my CSS file as style.css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 
    left: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px; 
    white-space: pre; 
}

.h1, h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    color: aqua;
}
```

And what I must to do in order to I make it work?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `padding-left: ` has no value.

Comment: In other words, you need to learn basic debugging, like opening your browser's debug console and looking for error messages.

Comment: What are you trying to change? You don't have a value for padding-left.

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, you aren't linking your style.css file in a <link> tag

Comment: @AlexJohnson What if he wants to style another element to look like a `h1`?

Comment: Good point! That's totally valid. Also, looking at the code above, there is a .h1 class in play ``<h1 class="h1">...```. I've editing my previous comment. thanks

Comment: You got to validate your HTML and CSS for incomplete statements, un-linked files etc.,

Comment: @ThomasMurphy Thank you for your answer because I'm tired and I missing my link to style.css file that was my problem with loaded CSS. Cheers

Comment: Sure thing @VictorS. Get some sleep, it will go better that way!

Answer (score 2):

You have "padding-left:" without providing a value. It is quite possible that the css is breaking due to a syntax error.

You probably either want to remove this line or put the desired value for the property